# How to get ITemplate from razor engine (IRazorEngineService)

Tags: razor, razorengine

I just updated our RazorEngine reference to version 3.7.5. A bunch of things seems to have changed and became obsolete. 
For most things I figured out 'the new way', except for 1 thing: getting an `ITemplate` instance.

We used to use a `TemplateService` instance. That had a method `Resolve`, which returns an `ITemplate` instance.

The TemplateService was replaced with `IRazorEngineService`. This doesn't have any method returning an `ITemplate`.

What's the correct way to retrieve one?

Answer (score 0):

As I already discussed this on some threads here some quotes:

> Can you elaborate the reasons why you need access to instances of that interface directly?
>   I decided to remove direct access to it as it isn't easy to use and mostly doesn't do what you think it does. It also can cause problems in case you use the Isolation API.

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/225

If its about setting custom layouts the proper upgrade path is to use a custom `TemplateBase` and make use of the ViewBag (as discussed on the linked issue).

The other more interesting use case is to get data OUT of the template.
This is discussed in detail here: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/238

Here is a code sample on how to get out the 'Subject' from the given template

Template:

```
@model HelloWorldModel
@{
    Layout = "CI";
    Subject = "Hello World";
}
Hello @Model.Name,<br/>
this is a test email...
```

Code (simplified)

```
class CustomDataHolder {
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
// In the custom TemplateBase class:
    public string Subject { get { return Viewbag.DataHolder.Subject; }; set { Viewbag.DataHolder.Subject = value; } }

// Your code
public static Task SendEmailAsync<T>(string templateName, string destination, T model)
{
    var holder = new CustomDataHolder ();
    dynamic viewbag = new DynamicViewBag();
    viewbag.DataHolder = holder;
    holder.Destination= destination;
    var body = Engine.Razor.Run(templateName, typeof(T), model, (DynamicViewBag)viewbag);

    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(holder.Destination));
    msg.Subject = holder.Subject;
    msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    return smtpClient.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```

Hope this covers your use case. Otherwise please add more information to your question on what you trying to achieve with the `ITemplate` instances....